# How to get a printer object and rename it in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I've been tasked by a client to rename several thousand printers across a dozen Windows 2008r2 nodes. Obviously, this is a job for powershell. But I only have PowerShell 2.0. I thought about deleting them and just rebuilding them but that would take even longer.

What I need to do here is grab a printer and change its name. Problem, and for the life of me, I can't find how to get a specific printer!

All I need to know is how to lookup a printer by its name (I've got a spreadsheet), take its object, and modify it to the new name. Help please!

Please note, I don't know how to use vbscript. I spent all yesterday and this morning trying to figure out how to use Win32_Printer in vb and I just give up.

Answer (score 2):

To interact with `Win32_Printer` in PowerShell, use `Get-WmiObject`:

```
$Printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE NAME = 'Printer01'"
```

Now, to rename the printer, call the [`RenamePrinter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393050(v=vs.85).aspx) method on `$Printer`:

```
$Rename = $Printer.RenamePrinter("NewPrinterName01")
if($Rename.ReturnValue -eq 0){
    Write-Host "Printer renamed"
} else {
    Write-Warning "Rename failed"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I think its working. The ISE is just sitting in a running state so, call that a win?